# Is it safe to drive Ford Fusion 2006 1.6 tdci with broken power steering pump

Tags: ford, power-steering

My power steering pump has failed on mentioned ford model and steering is harder but drivable. Is it safe to drive around 1000 miles with this issue, since I have no time to repair it and have already booked a vacation?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, no, maybe...

It depends on how it has failed.
If the internal seal etc failed so it just does not pump then probably yes.

If the bearings have failed and the pump will break and possibly damage something else then no.

If the pump seizes and takes the belt out, then whatever else driven by that belt also stops.

Comment: Most people can't handle to drive without power steering, so it's not really safe even if nothing breaks/seize.

Comment: @AsenM was driving at 12 years old and power steering was rare then. So knowing to turn when wheels are already rotating saves effort.

Comment: I know what you mean mean, but most can't even drive stick. I don't think it will be safe for them to go without power steering apart from that I agree with everything you have said.

Comment: @AsenM was towed in a chevy blazer that had a dead engine - no power steering, no power brakes and it was fine - but I have sufficient strength...